# How to get $refs using Composition API in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to get $refs in Vue 3 using Composition API. This is my template that has two child components and I need to get reference to one child component instance:

```
<template>
    <comp-foo />
    <comp-bar ref="table"/>
</template>
```

In my code I use [Template Refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html): ref is a special attribute, that allows us to obtain a direct reference to a specific DOM element or child component instance after it's mounted.

If I use Options API then I don't have any problems:

```
  mounted() {
    console.log("Mounted - ok");
    console.log(this.$refs.table.temp());
  }
```

However, using Composition API I get error:

```
setup() {
    const that: any = getCurrentInstance();
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log("Mounted - ok");
      console.log(that.$refs.table.temp());//ERROR that.$refs is undefined
    });
    return {};
  }
```

Could anyone say how to do it using Composition API?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You need to create the ref const inside the setup then return it so it can be used in the html.

```
<template>
    <div ref="table"/>
</template>

import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

setup() {
    const table = ref(null);

    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(table.value);
    });

    return { table };
}
```

Comment: The composition api work with setup function executing before on mounted function run,
Therefore you wont have access to DOM, so creating new variable give you a way to create a handle to what will hold a dom when `onMounted()` function run.
Am telling you man with composition api this is a trick around that problem

Comment: the variable you created on the html `ref` you wont have access to it on your `setup()` function since it run before `onMounted()` function have run. you only have access to it after a `onMounted()` function have executed,

Comment: Doesn't help. The `table.value` still comes out to be `null` for me.

Comment: @YashNag You probably need to create a new question so we can see your code.

Comment: @dantheman I made it work. It was a stupid oversight on my part. I was looking for this `ref` to be populated `onMounted`, but the component was dynamically loaded on certain conditions. Once i refactored the code for that, it worked just.

Comment: @YashNag can you post an example please? I stuck on this.

Comment: @AlpAltunel Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76603025/9549847) out. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I need a generic way and read all the $refs like in the old way.

Answer (score 13):

On Laravel Inertia:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

// a list for testing
let items = [
  { id: 1, name: "item name 1" },
  { id: 2, name: "item name 2" },
  { id: 3, name: "item name 3" },
];

// this also works with a list of elements
let elements = ref(null);

// testing
onMounted(() => {
    
  let all = elements.value;
  let item1 = all[0];
  let item2 = all[1];
  let item3 = all[2];

  console.log([all, item1, item2, item3]);

});
</script>
<template>
  <div>

    <!-- elements -->
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items" ref="elements" :key="item.id">

      <!-- element's content -->
      <div>ID: {{ item.id }}</div>
      <div>Name: {{ item.name }}</div>

    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: for some reason, the elements.value turns out null for me.

Comment: @FridoEmans what Vue version are you using?

Answer (score 5):

```
<template>
    <your-table ref="table"/>
    ...
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

setup() {
    const table = ref(null);

    onMounted(() => {
      table.value.addEventListener('click', () => console.log("Event happened"))
    });

    return { table };
}
</script>
```

Inside your other component you can interact with events you already registered on onMounted life cycle hook as with my example i've registered only one evnet

Comment: Yes,i've considered that and i've responded on my code with the lines below comment which read as `<!-- passing as reference to other component -->`

Comment: If i get you well is, you dont want that line on setup function where we say `const table = ref(null);` as is creating new variable right? @Pavel_K

Answer (score 4):

If you want, you can use `getCurrentInstance()` in the parent component like this code:

```html
<template>
    <MyCompo ref="table"></MyCompo>
</template>

<script>
import MyCompo from "@/components/MyCompo.vue"
import { ref, onMounted, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
export default {
    components : {
        MyCompo
    },
    
    setup(props, ctx) {
        
        onMounted(() => {
          getCurrentInstance().ctx.$refs.table.tempMethod()
           
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is the code of child component (here I called it `MyCompo`):

```html
<template>
    <h1>this is MyCompo component</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    
    setup(props, ctx) {
        
        const tempMethod = () => {
            console.log("temporary method");
        }

        return {
            tempMethod
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: getCurrentInstance() is technically ["internal" code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72209340/1431900) and as such its probably not a great idea to rely on it in prod code

Comment: @Graystripe I did not test it in prod codes, but because the actual question used ```getCurrentInstance()```, I found a solution that works with that.

Comment: Prod code as in, production code -- yes, it will work now, but it isn't officially "supported" and might break without warning in the future

Answer (score 3):

if you are using vue 3 with compostion api then **Template Ref** allows you to do this.

you can access the dom after the initial render. As **script setup** runs before dom creation. so using onMounted hook you can access the target element.

you can read this blog to know more about **template Ref**
https://medium.com/@plabonislam/how-to-access-dom-element-using-vue-3-compostion-api-2181d69abee6

```
<script setup>
 import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
 const headline=ref(null);
 onMounted(()=>{
 console.log(headline.value) 
 
 }
</script>

<template>
 <h1 ref="headline"> hello world </h1>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, the `ref` variable was not binding to the component because it was not yet **rendered**. I'll be extending [@dantheman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71094531/9549847). Consider the following:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="false">
        <div ref="table"/>
    </div>
</template>

import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

setup() {
    const table = ref(null);

    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(table.value);
    });

    return { table };
}
```

In this scenario where the `<div ref="table"/>` is not rendered because of the condition, the `const table` remains `null`. Let's say if the `false` turns into `true`, the `const table` is then populated. This is also clearly [stated here in the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs):

> Note that you can only access the ref after the component is mounted. If you try to access input in a template expression, it will be null on the first render. This is because the element doesn't exist until after the first render!

So it's not just `onMounted` that you have to look for, it's also whether the component to which `ref` is attached, is actually mounted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe TypeScript is easier for this. This worked for me:

```
const table = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
```

Comment: Is the 'table' then referenced by using the const variable name as table? - What if other elements as this.$refs.somethingElse is used. Would one the declare a const somethingElse = ref(null); ?

Comment: @DirkSchumacher Yes, which is ok for a few single elements. Otherwise you could store refs in an array.

Answer (score 0):

For using refs in an array, [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72835670/6243352) logs an empty refs array in Vue versions between 3.2.25 and 3.2.31 inclusive:

```js
const {ref, onMounted} = Vue;

Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const items = [
      {id: 1, name: "item name 1"},
      {id: 2, name: "item name 2"},
      {id: 3, name: "item name 3"},
    ];
    const elements = ref([]);
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(
        elements.value.map(el => el.textContent)
      );
    });
    return {elements, items};
  }
}).mount("#app");
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, i) in items" ref="elements" :key="item.id">
    <div>ID: {{item.id}}</div>
    <div>Name: {{item.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.31/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

A workaround is replacing `refs="elements"` with `:ref="el => elements[i] = el"`:

```js
const {ref, onMounted} = Vue;

Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const items = [
      {id: 1, name: "item name 1"},
      {id: 2, name: "item name 2"},
      {id: 3, name: "item name 3"},
    ];
    const elements = ref([]);
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(
        elements.value.map(el => el.textContent)
      );
    });
    return {elements, items};
  }
}).mount("#app");
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, i) in items"
       :ref="el => elements[i] = el"
       :key="item.id">
    <div>ID: {{item.id}}</div>
    <div>Name: {{item.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.31/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is fine for JavaScript, but if you are using Typescript typing doesn't work. I have an answer that should work here for typescript, and it would also work for javascript without the cumbersome on mounted in the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Using the TypesScript compatible defineComponent, you can pass the desired code off to a method that does indeed have this.$refs defined:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ModeBar',
  methods: {
    registerToolTips(): boolean {
      //this.$refs is available!!!
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => this.registerToolTips());
  },
});
```

The this.$nextTick() may not be always necessary, and may not be enough sometimes. There is no guarantee that everything you want is rendered on mounted. You may have to put an interval on mounted if the intended $refs are not yet rendered, and then turn it off when they are found;

This is why the registerToolTips returns a boolean, so that if it doesn't work I could try it again.