# VueJS 3 equivalent of JS Select() function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I want my code to select the password textbox when it does not matched with the confirm password textbox after clicking the register button. [Click here to see the image of the wanted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2B4H.png)

Is there an equivalent way of doing select() function in VueJS? The textbox that I want to be selected is in ref state.

I've tried value.select() but it showed on console that it is not a function.

Just a disclaimer that I'm still learning about VueJS and Quasar. Been googling and reading documents and still no luck.

Here's the code below.

```
<template>
    <div class="window-height window-width row justify-center items-center">
        <q-card class="my-card">
            <q-card-section class="col-10" style="width: 800px">
                <q-input v-model="nameTextBox" label="Name" />
                <q-input ref="email" v-model="emailTextBox" type="email" label="Email" />
                <q-input ref="password" v-model="passTextBox" type="password" label="Password" />
                <q-input v-model="conPassTextBox" type="password" label="Confirm Password" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <q-btn color="secondary" class="q-mr-lg"
                    @click="registerProfile(emailTextBox, nameTextBox, passTextBox, conPassTextBox)">
                    Register
                </q-btn>
                <q-btn :to="'/'">Cancel</q-btn>
            </q-card-section>
        </q-card>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

import { ref, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
const { $feathers } = getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties

const nameTextBox = ref('')
const emailTextBox = ref('')
const passTextBox = ref('')
const conPassTextBox = ref('')

const checkConfirmPassword = (pass, conPass) => {
  // console.log(pass, conPass)
  if (pass === conPass) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

const registerProfile = (emailText, nameText, passText, conPassText) => {
  console.log(emailText)
  $feathers.service('/users').find({
    query: {
      email: emailText
    }
  })
    .then(() => {
      // email found
      alert('Email has already been registered. Please use anothere email.')
      // ref.email.select()
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(checkConfirmPassword(passText, conPassText))
      if (checkConfirmPassword(passText, conPassText) === false) {
        alert('Password is the same. Please retype it again.')
        passTextBox.value.select() // -> This syntax does not work.
      } else {
        console.log('Passed')
        $feathers.service('/users').create({
          email: emailText,
          name: nameText,
          password: passText
        })
      }
    })
}

</script>
```

Comment: select() called on an input will work the same way whether in Vue or not.  I think the issue you're running into is that `ref.email` is undefined (did you mean `emailTextBox`?)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Daniel. Just commented the ref.email part as I'm trying solve on the password part first which it worked with the answer by Mr. R below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `select` method on the value of your password textbox (on a string!). You need to define your ref instances and use them. In order to define refs first, define ref names:

```js
const password = ref(null)
const email = ref(null)
```

then in the HTML part use the exact names for the ref prop:

```html
<q-input ref="email" v-model="emailTextBox" type="email" label="Email" />
<q-input ref="password" v-model="passTextBox" type="password" label="Password" />
```

and finally, use these variables to reference elements.

```js
password.value.select()
// or
email.value.select()
```

Full code would be:

```html
<template>
    <div class="window-height window-width row justify-center items-center">
        <q-card class="my-card">
            <q-card-section class="col-10" style="width: 800px">
                <q-input v-model="nameTextBox" label="Name" />
                <q-input ref="email" v-model="emailTextBox" type="email" label="Email" />
                <q-input ref="password" v-model="passTextBox" type="password" label="Password" />
                <q-input v-model="conPassTextBox" type="password" label="Confirm Password" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <q-btn color="secondary" class="q-mr-lg"
                    @click="registerProfile(emailTextBox, nameTextBox, passTextBox, conPassTextBox)">
                    Register
                </q-btn>
                <q-btn :to="'/'">Cancel</q-btn>
            </q-card-section>
        </q-card>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

import { ref, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
const { $feathers } = getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties

const nameTextBox = ref('')
const emailTextBox = ref('')
const passTextBox = ref('')
const conPassTextBox = ref('')

// Define refs to components. 
// Use this variable name as the one you set in the ref prop for the component.
const password = ref(null)
const email = ref(null)

const checkConfirmPassword = (pass, conPass) => {
  // console.log(pass, conPass)
  if (pass === conPass) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

const registerProfile = (emailText, nameText, passText, conPassText) => {
  console.log(emailText)
  $feathers.service('/users').find({
    query: {
      email: emailText
    }
  })
    .then(() => {
      // email found
      alert('Email has already been registered. Please use anothere email.')
      email.value.select() // this works either
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(checkConfirmPassword(passText, conPassText))
      if (checkConfirmPassword(passText, conPassText) === false) {
        alert('Password is the same. Please retype it again.')

        password.value.select() // -> This works know.

      } else {
        console.log('Passed')
        $feathers.service('/users').create({
          email: emailText,
          name: nameText,
          password: passText
        })
      }
    })
}
```

Please look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71093658/how-to-get-refs-using-composition-api-in-vue3) to figure out how refs work in Vue3 and composition API.

Comment: Thanks Mr. R. This worked like a charm and got a better understanding about ref.