# Why is it not possible to achieve reactivity with ref in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to change the value by clicking on the button, but Vue does not update this value, although it is updated in the console:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
let value = ref(false);
function update() {
    value =! value
    console.log(value); // changed
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="update">UPDATE</button>
  <p>
    {{ value }} - not changed
  </p>

</template>
```

I created an example in Vue SFC Playground: [https://sfc.vuejs.org/example_not_change_value](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kL1uwzAMhF+F1ZIEiK09dYIGaPcO7abFUejEqSwJEpUOht+9VOT+oAWqSSQP35E3ir339TWh2Igm6tB7goiU/E7ZfvAuEIwQsIMJuuAGWLB0oaxBgmtrEsI2T5ddayKu7pXtktXUOwvJH1vC5QpGZYHfrL4rn9LTzkZnsDbutLy1mUBSgj639oRHZSdlG1m24n24IBy8YS5XAM0hEbHVgza9ftsqUTyV2L0+P+5fnhpZBEWcL8qm4zjvMk1QgXX0bccqmWXZ9ctJrEUJohpaX1+isxzV7Sg1D6ISm88zleCAcq3EmcjHjZSx0zngS6xdOEn+1SFZ6gesMQ7VIbj3iIHBSqx/MCQ3rxiqgPaIAcN/zF/SP9yM5SgnMX0AoWqqiQ==)

Where do I make a mistake and how to fix it?

Comment: You can always prefer `const`  to `let` where applicable to avoid accidental reassignments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.value` in script when using `Ref`.
[This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71093658/how-to-get-refs-using-composition-api-in-vue3).

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
let value = ref(false);
function update() {
    value.value = !value.value
    console.log(value.value); // changed
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="update">UPDATE</button>
  <p>
    {{ value }} - not changed
  </p>

</template>
```