# How can I get the FullCalendar vue3 component to refresh?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, laravel-vue

I'm using the FullCalendar vue3 component with Laravel Breeze/Vue, but I haven't been able to get the calendar to refresh when needed.  I'd like the calendar to refresh after a select element changes to show a new calendar for a different user.

I'm using the Vue3 composition api, but I can't see how to force the calendar to refresh.  I think I need to use the Calendar api, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's a scaled down version of the code:

```
<script setup>
import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue';
import { reactive, ref, computed, watch, onMounted, onUnmounted, nextTick } from "vue";
import { Head, Link, useForm, router } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue3';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

const props = defineProps({
    'calendar_users': Object,
});

const calendarFor = reactive({
    id: -1,
});

const calendarOptions = reactive({
    plugins: [
        dayGridPlugin,
        timeGridPlugin,
        interactionPlugin,
    ],
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    headerToolbar: {
        start: 'prevYear,nextYear prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        end: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    events: '/get_events' + '?user=' + calendarFor.id,
    height: 'auto',
});

function refresh_calendar() {
    let calApi = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi();
    calApi.refetchEvents();
}

</script>

<template>
    <Head title="Calendar" />
    <AuthenticatedLayout>
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800">
                Office Calendar
            </h2>
        </template>
        <div class="py-3">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden sm:rounded-lg" id="CalendarScreen" name="CalendarScreen">
                    <div class="flex">
                        <div v-if="true" id="left_side" class="min-w-48 m-1 border">
                            <div class="flex mt-8">
                                <label for="calendarFor" class="ml-3 mr-4 font-bold text-lg">Calendar for:</label>
                                <select v-model="calendarFor.id" class=" border rounded-md" id="calendarFor"  @change="refresh_calendar()">
                                    <option value="-1">****</option>
                                    <option v-for="calendar_user in props.calendar_users" :key="calendar_user.id" :value="calendar_user.id">
                                        {{ calendar_user.initials }}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="right_side" class="">
                            <div class="p-4 text-gray-900">
                                <FullCalendar ref='fullCalendar' :options="calendarOptions" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </AuthenticatedLayout>
</template>
```

When the page loads the events are loaded and there are no errors.  But the following error occurs when I call the refresh_calendar() function when changing the calendar user:

[image: Screenshot of console error message.]

Also, here's some info from the Vue Devtools showing the ref to the calendar component:
[image: Screenshot of devtools showing ref.]

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get the fullcalendar vue3 component to refresh based upon the selected user?

Thanks

Comment: There's no "this" and no $refs in composition api

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71093658/how-to-get-refs-using-composition-api-in-vue3

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for your help!  I tried removing the this and $refs, but it wouldn't work just using fullCalendar or refs.fullCalendar.  Then explored info in the link you provided and I moved the calApi = fullCalendar.getApi(); line to the onMounted function.  But now I get an error stating that getApi is not a function.  So, it seems to be seeing the fullCalendar reference, but not finding the getApi() function.

Comment: Check the dupe question closely, it shows how it's done. I suppose you misused a composition ref because it should have been `fullCalendar.value.getApi()`

Comment: @EstusFlask That looks like it may have done the trick!  I forgot about the .value.  I'll explore this more when I get back later.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is having difficulty getting the Fullcalendar api functions to work with the Fullcalendar vue component in the composition api, I figured I'd post this.

The answer was explained in a comment above, referencing a possible duplicate question.  Because the script setup runs before the DOM is loaded, to get things working you need to put the call to getApi() in the onMounted function.

Here's a basic outline of what I did:

```
<script setup>
import { reactive, ref, computed, watch, onMounted, onUnmounted, nextTick } from "vue";

import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue3';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

const fullCalendar = ref(null);
let calApi = null;

const calendarOptions = reactive({
    plugins: [
        dayGridPlugin,
        timeGridPlugin,
        interactionPlugin,
    ],
   ...
});

onMounted(() => {
    calApi = fullCalendar.value.getApi();
});

</script>
<template>
    <FullCalendar ref='fullCalendar' :options="calendarOptions" />
</template>
```

Then, if you need to do something beyond what's available in calendarOptions, you can call any fullcalendar function using the calApi variable, for example, calApi.refetchEvents();

Thanks to Estus Flask above for helping sort this out!